# Issue creating a cookie in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been trying to create a cookie...

```
document.cookie = "gameData = 0";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

But each time, I look in the console and the output is entirely blank. Am I using the wrong syntax or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. Please check your browser setting and `Enable cookies`.

For Chrome:

[image: Go to <code>Settings => Show advance settings => Content Settings</code>]

For Firefox:

[image]